# Angular 5 Generic components and routing

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm building application based on Angular 5 and NGRX. One of my goals is to keep some basic, often used components as generics, held in my Core Module. Here is the structure:

[Structure graph img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39UAX.png)

So I have two generic components, Tile and Container. Tile is used inside Container. Components are declared in CoreModule. All others modules in my application make use of Container and its Tiles, so they import CoreModule. Everything works perfect by now.

Problem: Every Tile component has a `routerLink="..."` tag. I would like to define redirect path from level of the currently used module. By that I mean clicking on Tile in Module 1 will redirect me to path '/preview/:id', but clicking on Tile in Module 2 will redirect me to path '/lots/:id/preview'.

Router root is placed on CoreModule level. Other modules (Module 1,2,3) are lazy loaded, and each provides child routes.

I'm looking for something more clever than dummy passing route as a string by @Input, down the Container to Tile Component.

I was looking for something like 'name' parameter in angular router, so Tile calls for 'tileRedirection' route and then route named as 'tileRedirection' in current module defines next behavior, but it looks like angular has no named routes(!?)

Comment: This seems quite vague. Maybe you can provide some code from your tiles? Example, minimal reproduction of the thing you want to achieve?

Comment: recommend using @ngrx-router